# Flutter : Using String and boolean value in Map()

Tags: flutter, dart

Using both string and boolean value in Map return the following error, how can i use both values?.

```
var bodyValues = new Map<String, dynamic>();
bodyValues['accountName'] = accountName;
bodyValues['customerEmail'] = customerEmail;
bodyValues['getAllAvailableBanks'] = false;


final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'https:url',
    body: bodyValues,
   headers:headerValues
);
```

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code for the `http` package it is clear that if you provide a `Map` as `body` it needs to be `Map<String, String>`. You can see here where the `cast` is happening:

```
  @override
  Future<Response> post(Uri url,
          {Map<String, String>? headers, Object? body, Encoding? encoding}) =>
      _sendUnstreamed('POST', url, headers, body, encoding);
...

  /// Sends a non-streaming [Request] and returns a non-streaming [Response].
  Future<Response> _sendUnstreamed(
      String method, Uri url, Map<String, String>? headers,
      [body, Encoding? encoding]) async {
    var request = Request(method, url);

    if (headers != null) request.headers.addAll(headers);
    if (encoding != null) request.encoding = encoding;
    if (body != null) {
      if (body is String) {
        request.body = body;
      } else if (body is List) {
        request.bodyBytes = body.cast<int>();
      } else if (body is Map) {
        request.bodyFields = body.cast<String, String>();
      } else {
        throw ArgumentError('Invalid request body "$body".');
      }
    }

    return Response.fromStream(await send(request));
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/e89b190936d53d0e36148436283e28ba1091b35a/lib/src/base_client.dart#L87

Comment: How can I use a boolean then?

Comment: @chubi Well, you need to convert it to a `String`. If you use `toString()` on it, you will get `true` or `false` as strings.